# SilverStripe duplicating database field error, when runing dev/build

Tags: php, database, silverstripe

Hello i had to use older version for my SS project (SS 3.1.5). I add SS fluent (3.2.3)  to make my project multilanguage, everything works fine with , ENG, LAT, SW, DE languages but when i add Russian (RU) and then run dev/build i get duplicating DB column error. I get them even if i manually remove the columns.

This is one of the error messages what i get. Full build list and error list i posted here - https://github.com/tractorcow/silverstripe-fluent/issues/340

```
Couldn't run query: ALTER TABLE "SiteTree_Live" ADD "URLSegment_ru_RU" varchar(255) character set utf8 collate utf8_general_ci, ADD "Title_ru_RU" varchar(255) character set utf8 collate utf8_general_ci, ADD "MenuTitle_ru_RU" varchar(100) character set utf8 collate utf8_general_ci, ADD "Content_ru_RU" mediumtext character set utf8 collate utf8_general_ci, ADD "MetaDescription_ru_RU" mediumtext character set utf8 collate utf8_general_ci, ADD "ExtraMeta_ru_RU" mediumtext character set utf8 collate utf8_general_ci, ADD "ReportClass_ru_RU" varchar(50) character set utf8 collate utf8_general_ci, ADD index "URLSegment_ru_RU" ("URLSegment_ru_RU") Duplicate column name 'URLSegment_ru_RU'
MySQLDatabase.php:598
MySQLDatabase->databaseError(Couldn't run query: ALTER TABLE "SiteTree_Live" ADD "URLSegment_ru_RU" varchar(255) character set utf8 collate utf8_general_ci, ADD "Title_ru_RU" varchar(255) character set utf8 collate utf8_general_ci, ADD "MenuTitle_ru_RU" varchar(100) character set utf8 collate utf8_general_ci, ADD "Content_ru_RU" mediumtext character set utf8 collate utf8_general_ci, ADD "MetaDescription_ru_RU" mediumtext character set utf8 collate utf8_general_ci, ADD "ExtraMeta_ru_RU" mediumtext character set utf8 collate utf8_general_ci, ADD "ReportClass_ru_RU" varchar(50) character set utf8 collate utf8_general_ci, ADD index "URLSegment_ru_RU" ("URLSegment_ru_RU") | Duplicate column name 'URLSegment_ru_RU',256)
MySQLDatabase.php:150
MySQLDatabase->query(ALTER TABLE "SiteTree_Live" ADD "URLSegment_ru_RU" varchar(255) character set utf8 collate utf8_general_ci, ADD "Title_ru_RU" varchar(255) character set utf8 collate utf8_general_ci, ADD "MenuTitle_ru_RU" varchar(100) character set utf8 collate utf8_general_ci, ADD "Content_ru_RU" mediumtext character set utf8 collate utf8_general_ci, ADD "MetaDescription_ru_RU" mediumtext character set utf8 collate utf8_general_ci, ADD "ExtraMeta_ru_RU" mediumtext character set utf8 collate utf8_general_ci, ADD "ReportClass_ru_RU" varchar(50) character set utf8 collate utf8_general_ci, ADD index "URLSegment_ru_RU" ("URLSegment_ru_RU"))
MySQLDatabase.php:320
MySQLDatabase->alterTable(SiteTree_Live,Array,Array,Array,Array,,)
Database.php:223
SS_Database->endSchemaUpdate()
DatabaseAdmin.php:215
DatabaseAdmin->doBuild(,1)
DatabaseAdmin.php:100
DatabaseAdmin->build()
DatabaseAdmin.php:80
DatabaseAdmin->index(SS_HTTPRequest)
RequestHandler.php:288
RequestHandler->handleAction(SS_HTTPRequest,index)
Controller.php:194
Controller->handleAction(SS_HTTPRequest,index)
RequestHandler.php:200
RequestHandler->handleRequest(SS_HTTPRequest,DataModel)
Controller.php:153
Controller->handleRequest(SS_HTTPRequest,DataModel)
DevelopmentAdmin.php:146
DevelopmentAdmin->build(SS_HTTPRequest)
RequestHandler.php:288
RequestHandler->handleAction(SS_HTTPRequest,build)
Controller.php:194
Controller->handleAction(SS_HTTPRequest,build)
RequestHandler.php:200
RequestHandler->handleRequest(SS_HTTPRequest,DataModel)
Controller.php:153
Controller->handleRequest(SS_HTTPRequest,DataModel)
Director.php:366
Director::handleRequest(SS_HTTPRequest,Session,DataModel)
Director.php:152
Director::direct(/dev/build,DataModel)
main.php:189
```

Comment: Could it be that you want to translate too many fields in your `SiteTree` object?

Comment: But then it wont show error on every language , not specific on russian ?

Comment: as you have the other languages already in DB it only wants to create ru_RU now.